# Holder spaces via Littlewood-Paley decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

Consider the Littlewood-Paley decomposition of a tempered distribution $f$:
\begin{equation}
f = \tilde{\theta}(D)f + \sum_{k \geq 1} \theta(2^{-k}D)f.
\end{equation}
Here $(\tilde{\theta}, \theta)$ are smooth compactly supported functions ($\theta$ having a support contained in an annulus far from zero), satisfying the following dyadic partition of unity relation: 
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\theta}(\xi) + \sum_{k \geq 1} \theta(2^{-k}\xi) = 1, \quad \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
In addition, $\tilde{\theta}(D)$ (as well as $\theta(2^{-k}D)$) are Fourier multipliers (i.e., they are defined by $\mathcal{F}(\tilde{\theta}(D)f)(\xi) = \tilde{\theta}(\xi)f(\xi)$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$). For $0 < \alpha < 1$, consider $C^{0, \alpha}(\mathbb{R})$ the space of continous and bounded functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the Holder condition, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\exists c > 0 : \forall (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \quad |f(x) - f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
Assume that $f$ is continous and bounded and 
\begin{equation}
\| f \|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP} := \| \tilde{\theta}(D)f\|_{L^{\infty}} + \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{k\alpha} \|\theta(2^{-k}D)f \|_{L^{\infty}}  < +\infty.
\end{equation}
I am looking to prove the following estimates. Fix $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. First,

> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{k > N} 2 \|\theta(2^{-k}D)f\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \frac{\| f \|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP}}{2^{\alpha}-1} \frac{1}{2^{\alpha N}}.
> \end{equation}

Second,

> \begin{equation}
> \Big|\tilde{\theta}(D)f(x) - \tilde{\theta}(D)f(y) + \sum_{k=1}^{N}[\theta(2^{-k}D)f(x) - \theta(2^{-k}D)f(y)] \Big| \leq C|x-y|\sum_{k=1}^{N} 2^{k(1-\alpha)}\| f \|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP}
> \end{equation}

for some $C > 0$. Concering the first estimate, I "went in brutally" and I manage to obtain a bound like $\| f \|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP} \sum_{k > N} 2^{1-k\alpha}$, so I don't know how to go further. For the second estimate, I sense an impending use of semi-classical Bernstein inequalities but I fail to see how to apply it to obtain such a bound. Any hint is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have succeeded (sort of, modulo a factor 2) in proving the first estimate. Recall that when $|q| < 1$, the remainder of the associated geometric series writes
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} q^k = \frac{q^n}{1-q}.
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k>N}^\infty 2 \| \theta(2^{-k}D)f\|_{L^{\infty}} &= 2\sum_{k = N+1}^\infty \frac{2^{k\alpha}}{2^{k\alpha}} \| \theta(2^{-k}D)f\|_{L^{\infty}} \\
&\leq 2 \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{k\alpha} \| \theta(2^{-k}D)f\|_{L^{\infty}} \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k\alpha}} \\
&\leq 2\|f\|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP} \frac{2^{-(N+1)\alpha}}{1-2^{-\alpha}} =  \frac{2\|f\|_{C^{0, \alpha}}^{LP}}{2^{\alpha}-1}\frac{1}{2^{\alpha N}}.
\end{align}
I still don't know how to prove the second inequality.

Edit: I may have found a way to prove the second inequality (using a mean value inequality then applying some of the hypotheses) - I'll write it down as soon as I have some time.